# how to implement for_each in terraform avi gslb to create and attach multiple pool to gslb?

Tags: terraform, avi

I have below which creates avi gslbservice with a single pool created and attached to it. I would like to create a second pool created and attached to it. Can any one please guide?
I am new to terraform, I saw few tutorials on for_each fn. But not able to figure out, how to apply it for my need.
I have highlighted the block which create the gslb pool

```
resource "avi_gslbservice" "avi_gslbservice" {
name = "helloworldssl-gslb"
tenant_ref = data.avi_tenant.avi_tenant.id
domain_names = ["xxxxxxxxx"]
health_monitor_refs = [avi_healthmonitor.avi_healthmonitor_gslb.id]
enabled = true
pool_algorithm = "GSLB_SERVICE_ALGORITHM_GEO"
ttl = "30"
created_by = "xxxxxx"
description = "xxxxxx"
down_response {
type = "GSLB_SERVICE_DOWN_RESPONSE_ALL_RECORDS"
             }
**groups {
      priority = 10
      members {
              ip {
                type = "V4"
                addr = ""
                 }
         fqdn = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
         vs_uuid = ""
         cluster_uuid = ""
         ratio = 1
         enabled = true
         }              
      name = "helloworldssl-gslb-pool1"
      algorithm = "GSLB_ALGORITHM_TOPOLOGY"
      }**
}
```

Edit Aug 8th 2021 - For now I have a work around of duplicating whole groups block two times.

Comment: Please properly format your code. Currently, every line is at the same indentation level. Intent your lines properly. Reviewers are more likely to help if they don't have to "unjumble" the formatting.

Comment: fixed json formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you do it,

```
dynamic "groups" {   
   for_each = var.avi_gslbservice_groups
   content {
      dynamic "members" {
        for_each = groups.value.avi_gslbservice_groups_ip
        content {
            ip {
                 type = "V4"
                 addr = ""
              }
              fqdn = members.value["host"]
              vs_uuid = ""
              cluster_uuid = ""
              ratio = 1
              enabled = members.value["enabled"]
            }         
          }                 
        name = groups.value["name"]
        priority = groups.value["priority"]
        algorithm = groups.value["algorithm"]
      }
     }
```

values will come from json file as below,

```
{
    "avi_gslbservice_groups": [
        {
            "name": "us-east-1",
            "priority": 7,
            "algorithm": "GSLB_ALGORITHM_ROUND_ROBIN",
            "avi_gslbservice_groups_ip": [
                {
                    "host": "host1",
                    "enabled": "true"
                },
                {
                    "host": "host2",
                    "enabled": "false"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "us-east-2",
            "priority": 10,
            "algorithm": "GSLB_ALGORITHM_TOPOLOGY",
            "avi_gslbservice_groups_ip": [
                {
                    "host": "host1",
                    "enabled": "true"
                },
                {
                    "host": "host2",
                    "enabled": "false"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to say that simon's answer is correct, I just want to expand something: to clarify and because there aren't many examples out there right now, the dynamic block that @Simon suggest produces a terraform configuration that looks like this:

```
groups {
  name = "us-east-1"
  priority = 7
  algorithm = "GSLB_ALGORITHM_ROUND_ROBIN"

  members {
    ip {
      type = "V4"
      addr = ""  
    }
    fqdn = "host1"
    vs_uuid = ""
    cluster_uuid = ""
    ratio = 1
    enabled = "true"
  }

  members {
    ip {
      type = "V4"
      addr = ""  
    }
    fqdn = "host2"
    vs_uuid = ""
    cluster_uuid = ""
    ratio = 1
    enabled = "false"
  }
}
```

I just wanted to explain this in case you don't understand why a [dynamic](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks) block is being used here, it is simple to use it to not repeat the same structure in HCL every time.